# Has the blog been effective?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

Has [the blog](http://gamingse.wordpress.com/) for Gaming.SE ([original post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/895/a-blog-for-gaming-se)) been effective at all at garnering users or interest?   Has it even gotten many views?

I ask because we're considering something similar over at [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: We have a blog?

Answer (score 5):

As one of the people involved in starting the blog, I would have to say no. It's totalled around 500 views in 2 months. My personal blog gets more than that, even without any sort of inbuilt community to aim it at. I'd wager that most of the visits to the blog come from metagaming and chat.gaming .

So, why didn't the blog work? My thoughts are:

- **Lack of activity** - We didn't have a regular posting schedule, just a few bursts of activity. Most of this is because it ended up being just the DF succession game and tzenes posting on it.
- **Lack of promotion** - Blogs work to build traffic by people reading an interesting article on the blog, and then thinking about checking out the associated site. It's what worked for the SO blog originally with the podcasts, for Joel On Software as far as promoting Fog Creek went, and for [Signal Vs Noise](http://37signals.com/svn/)'s articles on design. Traffic from the blog was driven to the site, while the opposite was happening with the gaming blog.
- **Lack of community activity** - In that whole time, the blog had 4 comments. There were no interesting discussions between community members in the comments. As shown in the comments to this question, some users didn't even know we had a blog.

What these have in common is that they are down to the implementation of this blog, not a flaw in the blog theory as a whole.

Comment: Another reason might be lack of branding/focus. I had read some of the articles there but I didn't realize it was an "official" gaming.SE blog.; I saw the URL at wordpress and assumed it was a private blog by some of our regulars. I would have thought an official blog would be within the gaming.SE.com domain and would focus on matters directly related to the SE.

Comment: It's currently unofficial. The official word from SO Inc. was that if the community organised a successful one, then they would consider endorsing it.

Comment: While it hasn't worked out yet, doesn't mean we shouldn't have to keep trying. Not everyone will have an RSS feed set up for the blog, most will just stumble over great posts. We just need to keep trying a little bit harder perhaps

Comment: So the biggest problem I found was that I could never get anyone else to post an article.  I set up a number of people with accounts and others promised they would too, but no one ever really followed through (with the exception of the DF game).

Comment: To be honest I'd rather have a lively chat than a lively blog...